# Domain level cookie in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-api, mvc

I need to set main domain(**abc.dis.com**) cookie in my sub domain(**xyz.dis.com**) in sitecore,please suggest.
Please find the below code snippet,but it's not working.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try cook.Domain = ".dis.com"

Answer (score 1):

The multiple domains can only share cookies if the domain is explicitly set in the Set-Cookie header. Otherwise, if you specify the scope like you did "`abc.dis.com`" the scope of the cookie will be restricted to the that host only.

For instance, if you sent the following header from abc.dis.com:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value
```

Then the cookie won't be sent for requests to `xyz.dis.com`.

But if you use the following, it will be created for all the subdomains like xyz.dis.com, lmn.dis.com, abc.dis.com etc.

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=dis.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify another subdomain (`abc.dis.com`) from subdomain `xyz.dis.com`.

What you can do is to assign a cookie to top level domain `dis.com` and all the subdomains like `abc.dis.com`, `xyz.dis.com` or `anything.dis.com` will be able to access that cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=.dis.com
```

So your code should be

```
cook.Domain = ".dis.com"
```

or

```
cook.Domain = "dis.com"
```

The first code supports old specification. Nowadays, in most of the browsers trailing dot is not necessary.

You can read more about cookies in [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives) article